# Software better than mindmap

Tags: mind-mapping

Mindmap is less "productive" than 'table' and 'data structure'.

for instance:

```
From_4P_to_4C = [('Project Product', 'Costomer Solution'),
                 ('Product Price', 'Customer Cost'),
                 ('Prodcut Place', 'Costomer Conveniece'),
                 ('Product Promotion', 'Customer Communication')]
```

Data structure works much better.

Is there any other software recommended to collect and organize information?

Comment: How do you want to use this information? just to look at it, or to import it into a program? What you have there looks liek JSON, so maybe a JSON editor? Or a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database? It's still not really clear what you want, sorry. The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you. Please also state your operating system and whether the solution should be free, or if you have a budget. Welcome aboard - give us some more information and we will try our best to help you

Comment: Adding to what @Mawg correctly suggested: please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) to get an idea what is expected. Your current conditions apply to too broad a spectrum, from databases/NoSQL to complete CMS. Here at SR, questions must be specific.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ... https://github.com/laurent22/joplin/

Comment: ty for the recommendation. @Mawg

Comment: I can recommend many others - but I don't really know what you are looking for. If you describe it better, then I can help more. The point is that you have to help us to help you. Maybe https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-notes-organizer.htm or https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-pim.htm might help?